# Using LUKS keyfile on external USB with grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, luks

I am trying to encrypt my laptop with an external USB disk. However, every time I boot up grub prompts me with a `'Enter passphrase for $DISK ($UUID):'`. This prompt allows me to unlock the disk with the temporary password I have setup. However, it ignores the USB.

The `/boot` partition is not encrypted. I have added the entry to the `crypttab`.

Is there any way of getting grub to read the keyfile off the usb, or leave 
decryption to the Linux boot?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up dm-crypt to use the keyfile?

```
# cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 /etc/mykeyfile
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Keyfiles

Once you've done that (and tested it manually), you need to get the removable drive recognized at boot:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#With_a_keyfile_stored_on_an_external_media

I apologize for just giving you links, but the alternative is to copy that wiki page verbatim.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the ubuntu equivalent (initramfs), which means I do not have to enter the key twice, but still forces me to enter it with the grub2 bootloader.

Comment: When at the grub menu, if you hit 'e' to see which grub config is about to launch (brings up a basic text editor), do you see the 'cryptkey' kernel parameter?

Comment: No. However, I changed this through `nano /etc/default/grub && update-grub`, and it made no difference to the cmdline. Adding `cryptkey=/dev/sdb1:vfat:/key` in manually on the grub edit prompt gets luks to prompt me for a password